# Laravel Upsert and Delete Unmatched Row

Tags: laravel

I Have a table named proposal_package_proposals with fields are id, proposal_id, and package_id. We can do Upser like this

```
ProposalPackageProposal::upsert([
    ["proposal_id"=>4,"proposal_package_id"=>41],
    ["proposal_id"=>4,"proposal_package_id"=>42],
], ["proposal_id"], ["proposal_package_id"]);
```

it will add 4-41 and 4-42 to the records, but what if we upsert 4-41 and 4-43 it should delete 4-42 and if we upsert 4-43 it should delete 4-41 and 4-42. Thank you in advance

Comment: You have to use relation here. Please make relation for respective model and use `sync()` method.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Please check my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309968/7796116) here. It will help.

Comment: @Vdpawar yes i have packages relation in Proposal model if i do Proposal::find(4)->packages it returns all related packages correctly, can you give an example how to sycn it?

Comment: good hint, i do it myself

Comment: `$proposal->packages()(relation)->sync(array of packages which you want to sync with this proposal);`

Kindly check [sync()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) so you can have an idea about it.